# Appending html with each function

Tags: jquery, html, json, append

This is my first question here... be gentle. ;-)

I'm running into a snag with a simple error display on a form of mine, Hopefully someone can shed some light on this.

Code:

```
$(json.error).each(function(i, item){
    $('#returned').append('<span class=error>&nbsp;'+item+'&nbsp;<span><br />');
});
```

So what I'm attempting to do is populate a div with the error's that are returned from my processing script.

The problem with appending this way is the IE doesn't recognize the class and apply my styling. I also tried

```
$(json.error).each(function(i, item){
    $('#returned').html('<span class=error>&nbsp;'+item+'&nbsp;<span><br />');
});
```

IE liked that... however, it only shows the last error in the returned json array.

I'm still very new to coding and not sure the proper method to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I could be wrong but I think all you need are the doublequotes around the error class.

Comment: Just a couple of guidelines - it should be class="error" not class=error. Don't use &nbsp; if you don't have to, and certainly don't use <br/> to add a new line.

Comment: Why, exactly, is using `&nbsp` and `<br />` bad, here?

Comment: I use the &nbsp to pad my returned message from the edges of the span (the css is red so I wanted a space on either side so it doesn't run into the edges of the letters), the <br /> is to seperate the messages. (up to 4 possible errors depending on inputs not entered)

Comment: @Stuck I get what you're trying to achieve, but it's bad practice to use html for visuals. Use CSS to style the outcome instead.

Comment: @NeXXeus it's not bad in that it causes an error, it's just bad practice.

Comment: @eagerMoose, thank you for setting me straight... and I agree with what you're saying... however, in light of that... how would I add the padding to either side of the error and the next line??

Comment: @Stuck I don't know what the rest of your structure is, but I'd use an unordered list ( <ul> ) here and put each error in a separate list item (<li>) then style list items not to have any bullets on the left and to have padding-left and padding-right

Comment: @eagerMoose, Thank you! Never even crossed my mind to use a list. Shows how new I still am... but hey... learn something new everyday. ;) Thank you again!

Comment: Update** Works a treat and so much cleaner. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think all you need are the doublequotes around the error class.

```
$(json.error).each(function(i, item){
    $('#returned').append('<span class="error">&nbsp;'+item+'&nbsp;<span><br />');
});
```

Comment: you are correct. I noticed it just after I posted this question. I'm a n0b... i know. =(

Answer (score 0):

Try your first approach with a separate call to the `addClass` method like this:

```
$(json.error).each(function(i, item){
    $('#returned').append('<span>&nbsp;'+item+'&nbsp;<span><br />').addClass('error');
});
```